# Objective-C NSMutableArray process 15 items at a time

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` like so:

```
NSMutableArray *value = [productionSchedule valueForKeyPath:@"Value"];
```

When populated this `NSMutableArray` could have 900 rows or just 8 or 12, There is no way of knowing, so what I am trying to do is process the first 15 rows and then the next 15 rows and so on till its done.

I am able to to process the first 15 rows with this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
}
```

But then how would I process the next 15 from `NSMutableArray`?

Here is the full loop in question:

```
for(int i = 0; i< [prodSchedSortedKeys count]; i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *valueArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSArray *baseLineFinishArray = [value objectAtIndex:i];

    for(int j = 0 ;j< [newTaskData count]; j++)
    {
        ProductionCellData *pModel = [[ProductionCellData alloc]init];

        if([[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"]  isEqual: @"Closing Date"])
        {
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a"];
            pModel.baseLineStart = [self SetSpecialDateFormat:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"]]WithOption:0];
            pModel.taskItem = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];
            [valueArray addObject: pModel];
        }
        else if([[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"]  isEqual: @"Days To Closing"])
        {
            [pModel setCellColor:[self SetCellColor:[[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"] intValue]]];
            pModel.baseLineStart = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"];
            pModel.taskItem = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];
            [valueArray addObject: pModel];
        }
        else if([[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"]  isEqual: @"Schedule Variance"])
        {
            [pModel setCellColor:[self SetCellColor:[[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"] intValue]]];
            pModel.baseLineStart = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"];
            pModel.taskItem = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];
            [valueArray addObject: pModel];
        }
        else if([[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"]  isEqual: @"Days Of Construction"])
        {
            [pModel setCellColor:[self SetCellColor:[[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"] intValue]]];
            pModel.baseLineStart = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"];
            pModel.taskItem = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];
            [valueArray addObject: pModel];
        }
        else if([[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"]  isEqual: @"NOTES"])
        {
            pModel.baseLineStart = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"];
            pModel.taskItem = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];
            [valueArray addObject: pModel];
        }
        else if([[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"]  isEqual: @"PDI To Close"])
        {
            [pModel setCellColor:[self SetCellColor:[[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"] intValue]]];
            pModel.baseLineStart = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"];
            pModel.taskItem = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];
            [valueArray addObject: pModel];
        }
        else
        {
            [pModel setTextCol:[self SetTextColor:[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j]]];
            [pModel setCellColor:[self SetCellColor:[self DateDifference:[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j]]]];
            NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss a"];
            pModel.baseLineStart = [self SetSpecialDateFormat:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"baselinefinish"]]WithOption:0];
            pModel.actualFinish =  [self SetSpecialDateFormat:[dateFormatter dateFromString:[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"actualenddate"]]WithOption:0];
            pModel.taskItem = [[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];
            [valueArray addObject:pModel];
            [dateFormatter release]; dateFormatter=nil;
        }
        [pModel release];
        pModel = nil;
    }

    [finalProductionSchedule setObject:valueArray forKey:[prodSchedSortedKeys objectAtIndex:i]];
    [valueArray release];
    valueArray = nil;
}
```

`[prodSchedSortedKeys count]` could be over 900, or just 12, its the count of number of rows of data.

After doing some debugging, I have determined that this is slowing everything down and taking up memory:

```
- (NSString *)SetSpecialDateFormat:(NSString *)date
{

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *theDate = date;
    NSArray *array = [theDate componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    dateFormat = nil;
    return [array objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, do you want to add a *delay* between processing every 15 items? What if the array changes in the meantime? It's mutable...

Comment: Basically when I loop through for an example 906 rows, Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue, So I am trying to think of away to prevent this.

Comment: You need to put a lot more relevant details in your question. Show what you are really doing and show where the memory issue is happening. There are too many unknowns to offer proper answers appropriate to your (unknown) issue.

Comment: This is a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You are asking about a problem which you don't actually have. The real problem is that you are running out of memory and you should be asking why that happens in the first place.

Comment: I add my full loop that is giving me trouble.

Comment: you need autoReleasePool , Also you don't provide full content from the beginning which will change the root of question

Comment: @Sh_Khan......Where?

Comment: Why aren't you using ARC? Save yourself a lot of headache and use ARC. And avoid so much redundant code as well. And avoid creating the same date formatter over and over.

Comment: Factorize your code. Make it readable. At least do `NSString *task = [[[baseLineFinishArray objectAtIndex:j] valueForKey:@"task"];` and use it. For the `isEqual:` or the `if/else if` tests, or the `pModel.taskItem = `. Stop allocating/initializing everytime a `NSDateFormatter` create one for once, and use it to translate the dates. Note that I also don't understand why you use an array in your `SetSpecialDateFormat:`.